# Unique elements in each column of an array (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, unique, element, vectorization

I might be a bit rusty with Matlab, maybe the answer to this question is more trivial than I imagine at this moment. However I have searched online for efficient solutions and I haven't found any, so I will try here.

I have a large matrix, something like y here:

```
N = 1e6; k = 20; n = 100;
y = ceil(n * rand(k, N));
```

For each column of the array I would like to count the number of unique elements. The loop is very slow:

```
tic
r = zeros(N, 1);
for ii = 1:N
  r(ii) = numel(unique(y(:, ii)));
end
toc
```

Looking for a vectorised, faster version.

---

**David**'s answer seems correct and fast too. Thank you!

```
N = 1e6; k = 20; n = 100;
y = ceil(n * rand(k, N));

tic
r1 = zeros(N, 1);
for ii = 1:N
  r1(ii) = numel(unique(y(:, ii)));
end
toc

tic
r2 = sum(diff(sort(y)) ~= 0) + 1;
toc

all(r1' == r2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
sum(diff(sort(y))~=0)+1
```

which uses functions that do vectorise. Performance seems better than your `for` loop for your case, however I'd imagine for larger problems my proposed solution would get worse due to memory limitation.

With `N=1e5`, your method takes ~7.5s on my computer, and my proposal takes ~0.05s. With `N=1e6`, the timings are ~75s and ~0.75s.

Comment: too bad swift can't do things like this.

Comment: @SanthanSalai `unique` effectively does that as well, it just isn't written with this type of thing in mind. It does `t=sort(y)` then `find(t(1:end-1)~=t(2:end))`, but isn't set up to deal with matrices like this.